# Keras RMSProp - what is the difference between "decay" and "weight_decay"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The "decay" parameter is no longer available for RMSProp after Keras 2.3. Now there's a "weight_decay" parameter - is that the same as "decay" from Keras < 2.3?

Comment: if you want to use L2 regularization with RMSProp optimizer in Keras 2.3 or later versions, you can set the `weight_decay` parameter to a non-zero value,but if you want to decay the learning rate over time,you should use a different optimizer or a learning rate scheduler